# Android MediaPlayer not working in Nougat

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

> I am trying to play media file, this code is working fine for below android N, but its not working for Nougat, please suggest me the best way to play media file on all android version.

```
private void Beep(String flag)
{
    if(flag=="1")
    {
        if(beepPlay==null)
        {
            beepPlay= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alarmsound);
            beepPlay.setLooping(true);
            beepPlay.setVolume(100,100);
        }
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20, 0);
        beepPlay.start();
        ((Vibrator)getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(2000);
    }
    else
    {
        if(beepPlay!=null) {
            beepPlay.stop();
            beepPlay.release();
            beepPlay = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: does it crash or what?

Comment: app is not crashing, media file is not being played.

Comment: Did you on Do not disturb mode on nougat device?
It might be a cause as per this documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume(int, int, int)

Comment: no, DND mode is not on. Same code is working for Marshmallow and other android version below N.

Comment: @AmmyKang Were you able to resolve it ?

Comment: no, am still looking for the solution.

Comment: do I need to change file format, file that I am using is .wav file which is working fine for below android N. I've also tried with .mp3 file which is again not working for android N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved the issue. there was a silly mistake in my code that's why the code was not running in Nougat. I just have replaced this piece of code if(flag=="1") with  if(flag.equals("1"))